# BIND/RNDC - Why do my subzones work and my actual zone doesn't?

Tags: linux, unix, domain, bind, rndc

Here is my named.conf:

```
view    "external"
{

        match-clients           { any; };
        match-destinations      { any; };

        recursion no;

        allow-query-cache { none; };

        include "/etc/named.root.hints";

        zone "domain.com" IN {
                type master;
                file "domain.com";
        };
};
```

and my domain.com

```
$TTL 86400
@               IN      SOA     ns1.domain.com.      admin.domain.com. (
                        2010111501
                        28800
                        7200
                        864000
                        86400
                        )
                IN      NS      ns1.domain.com.
                IN      NS      ns2.domain.com.

@                       A       109.228.16.159

$ORIGIN domain.com.

@               IN      A       109.228.16.159
domain.com.  IN      A       109.228.16.159
catch           IN      A       109.228.16.159
mail            IN      A       109.228.16.159

domain.com.  IN      MX      10 mail.domain.com.

ns1             IN      CNAME   catch
ns2             IN      CNAME   catch
www             IN      CNAME   catch
*               IN      CNAME   catch
```

www.domain.com works fine
ashfajkshfjkashfjkahskfjhasjkhfajksf.domain.com works fine
domain.com doesn't work

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move $ORIGIN to the top of your file.  Remove the second A definition for @ and the A definition for domain.com.  You may want to replace the @ definition with IN as follows.

```
$ORIGIN domain.com.
$TTL 86400
@               IN      SOA     ns1.domain.com.      admin.domain.com. (
                        2010111502
                        28800
                        7200
                        864000
                        86400
                        )
                IN      NS      ns1.domain.com.
                IN      NS      ns2.domain.com.
                IN      A       109.228.16.159

catch           IN      A       109.228.16.159
mail            IN      A       109.228.16.159
...
```

Check your logs for messages from bind when you restart it.

Comment: Did this actually work?  @ should be automatically defined to be the zone being loaded, so the $ORIGIN line should have no effect as it simply sets it again.

Comment: @michael I believe the $ORIGIN is redundant, but it doesn't hurt.  Likely breaks things severely if it doesn't match the domain it is configuring.  That may be a good thing.